# How to chain q.nfcall syncronous

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I read some tutorials but I don't understand how to chain various promises to read files but one after the other, I think its really easy, but I dont get it.

The idea is open one file, read the filename of the other file, open that file and then start the express server. I got something like this but I think I'm doing not really good, its working but I dont like it.

My code looks like this:

```
Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, path.resolve(__dirname, './config/db/default.connection.json'), "utf-8")
    .then(function(data){   ...
          /*HERE I OPEN OTHER 'Q' PROMISE FOR READ OTHER FILE AND START SERVER*/
             Q.nfcall(..). then(function(data2){ ... })
                   .catch(function(err){.. });
                  }). fail(function(err){...})
                    .done();
})
        .catch(function(err) {  ...});
})
       .fail(function(err) {..  })
        .done();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain promises by returning a new promise from a `.then()` handler,

```
Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'file1.txt').then(function(data1) {
  console.log('file 1 read');
  return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'file2.txt'); // return a new promise
}).then(function(data2) {
  console.log('file 2 read');
}).catch(function(err) {
  ...
}).done();
```

Errors/exceptions will be propagated along the chain as well.

**EDIT:** in case you want to errors reading `file1.txt` to not propagate, but instead handled in a different way (create the file instead), you could use something like this:

```
Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'test1.txt', 'utf-8').then(null, function(err) {
  // create an empty file (or whatever)
  return Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, 'test1.txt', '').then(function() {
    return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'test1.txt', 'utf-8');
  });
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('data 1', data);
  return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'test2.txt', 'utf-8');
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('data 2', data);
}).catch(function(err) {
  ...
});
```

(which can probably be done even more concise)

Comment: The `.done` is pretty redundant but OP had it too so I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah I wasn't too sure about it (perhaps some Q idiom) so I left it in.

Comment: Q will now gladly report unhandled rejections (since 1.3) which you can listen to using `process.on("unhandledRejection", function(p, reason){` so that idiom is largely outdated :)

Comment: @robertklep How i can do if the fail of the first call returned to other state but continues. In this case if try to open a file and exists is all ok, but it doesnt: create the file and then continue with the next Promise.

If i create two promises, the second promise only do when the first end?.

Q.nfcall(...).then(function1(..)).fail().done()

Q.nfcall(...).then(function2(..)).fail().done()